# How to get swagger to use both, the @applicationPath and @path

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-2.0

Swagger version: 2.0.7

I have an application with @applicationPath("/rest") and various @path("/shop/fruits").

The real endpoint is /rest/shop/fruits.
But swagger is considering the endpoint as /shop/fruits. 
Even after pointing the resourcepackage to the application paths file, it is not working.

```
    oas.info(info);
    SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
            .openAPI(oas).resourcePackages(Stream.of("com.shops.rest").collect(Collectors.toSet()));


    try {
        new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder()
                .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
                .buildContext(true);
    } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

I don't want to update my application path for this. Any solution which I should try.
Swagger 2.0 has support for @applicatioPath but still it's not considering the complete path.

Comment: Did you found a solution for that?